# How to ensure a Bluetooth connection is closed when it was started in another activity?

Tags: android, multithreading, socket.io, android-bluetooth

The APP I am developing connects to a Bluetooth Printer (the microFlash 2te for those curious) .

The Bluetooth connection is managed by a BluetoothConnectionManager class with a message handler at activity level to handle the information from the BluetoothChatService.

When I leave the activity in a controlled environment I make sure to disconnect the Bluetooth connection by stopping the bluetoothConnectionManager which stops all threads.

However when the user exits with the back button I cannot ensure the threads are stopped. This causes issues if I try and connect the socket as the Bluetooth device is already connected.

Is there away I can find and use or kill the bluetoothConnectionManager created by another activity? Or is there a way to ensure that a bluetoothConnectionManager stops when an activity is closed?

Attached is my connect thread class inside the BluetoothConnectionManager:

```
    private class ConnectThread extends Thread {
    private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
    private final BluetoothDevice mmDevice;

    public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device) {
        mmDevice = device;
        BluetoothSocket tmp = null;

        // Get a BluetoothSocket for a connection with the
        // given BluetoothDevice
        try {
            tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "create() failed", e);
        }
        mmSocket = tmp;
    }

    public void run() {
        Log.i(TAG, "BEGIN mConnectThread");
        setName("ConnectThread");

        // Always cancel discovery because it will slow down a connection
        mAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

        //stop();

        // Make a connection to the BluetoothSocket
        try {
            // This is a blocking call and will only return on a
            // successful connection or an exception
            d("About to connect to socket...");
            mmSocket.connect();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            connectionFailed();
            // Close the socket
            try {
                mmSocket.close();


            } catch (IOException e2) {
                d(e2.getMessage().toString());
                Log.e(TAG,
                        "unable to close() socket during connection failure",
                        e2);
            }
            return;
        }

        // Reset the ConnectThread because we're done
        synchronized (BluetoothConnectionManager.this) {
            mConnectThread = null;
        }

        // Start the connected thread
        connected(mmSocket, mmDevice);
    }

    public void cancel() {
        try {
            mmSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "close() of connect socket failed", e);
        }
    }
}
```